# Improper firefox refresh after query dialog submission

Tags: php, jquery, dialog

I have a page where I open a dialog, do some editing then submit and return to the same page, the thing is when I return, the page is not reloaded improperly to reflect the change in data ONLY in firefox.

here is how I open the dialog:

```
function addProduct() {

        $('#pop').load("newProduct.php").dialog({
        width: 470,
        height: 600,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'Products',
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function () {
                $('#pop').dialog("close");
            },
            Submit: function () {

                $("#formproduct").submit();

            }
        }
    });

    }
```

The code works fine in safari and chrome. Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Good thinking I found the problem, will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in the error console

Warning: The page was reloaded, because the character encoding declaration of the HTML document was not found when prescanning the first 1024 bytes of the file. The encoding declaration needs to be moved to be within the first 1024 bytes of the file.
Line: 15

It didnt ring a bell at first, but when I moved the meta directive for encoding to be the first in the page it worked fine.